# Авторизация на сайте с помощью python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, авторизация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Еще один вопрос на эту тему.
Есть тестовый сайт(он внутренний, посмотреть в живую не возможно) на котором надо авторизоваться, пикчи там нет, запрос выглядит так:

```
-----------------------------259453718138943564301838662474
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="XCSRFTokenF"

CfLJ8OV_ly7Ch80Iryc-kXeMXRJa0lVOfP5_Dg3h9HrqEV0JcjwepmXwideWUlciaEvmHcocZfxWjcBHWeCC7k_KVLzPqqnVmepViR8AKHin66FHGNn1MjjTTvrTuNznOavFyJzVBsSFUfDgWxO1oAYp0ag
-----------------------------259453718633943564301838662477
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ReturnUrl"

/ClientDevice
-----------------------------259453718633943564301838662477
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Email"

test@mail.ru
-----------------------------259453718633943564301838662477
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="PasswordUser"

1qaz@WSX
-----------------------------259453718633943564301838662477--
```

В теме не особо разбираюсь, посмотрел кучу видосов, у всех почемуто даже запрос внешне отличается в браузере в инструменте разработчика.
Наивно попробовал следующий код:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36 '
}

data = {
    "Email":"test@mail.ru",
    "PasswordUser":"1qaz@WSX"
    "ReturnUrl":"/ClientDevice"
}

url = "http://lk.testsite.ru/Account/Login"

s = requests.Session()
s.post(url, data=data, header=headers)
r = s.get("http://lk.testsite.ru/systemparameter") 
#здесь пытаюсь забрать страницу, которуую нельзя увидеть без авторизации
print(r.text)
#здесь разочарованно смотрю на код страницы авторизации
```

Подозреваю что часть проблемы в ""XCSRFTokenF".
Что собственно надо сделать?(

Comment: Поставьте Fiddler https://www.telerik.com/fiddler и запустите его. Затем пойдите вручную на этот ваш сайт и авторизуйтесь. В фидлере посмотрите, какие запросы отправлял ваш браузер и что получал в ответ. Затем пытайтесь повторить эти запросы в питоне.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Токен `XCSRFTokenF` **нужно на странице сайта вытаскивать** из тега `input`. Это защита, которая заставляет сначала загрузить страницу сайты, после сделать с нее запрос.

На сайте данные отправляются в другом формате. При отправке через `data=` данные будут как `Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, а у сайта данные отправляются в `Content-Type = multipart/form-data` (параметр `files=` в `post`), такое можно посмотреть в инспекторе браузере в заголовках запроса.

Для отправки в `multipart/form-data` поменяйте атрибут на `files`:

```
r = s.post(url, files=data, header=headers)
print(r)
```

Comment: Уже стало понятнее, может сможете еще чуть чуть мне разжевать)
Токен я вроде забрал, вроде подставил, но все ровно 400я
Вот код: https://codeshare.io/5wwnEB
Тут какой то составной запрос видимо нужен, вот заголовок: https://codeshare.io/ayeoW0

Comment: В коде у вас XCSRFTokenF, а по второй ссылке передается XCSRFTokenH. Это опечатка? Или сайт меняет название токена? Кроме того, возможно сайту нужен заголовок `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` Еще, по коду вы делаете запрос на http://lk.testsite.ru/ , а во второй ссылке это `/Account/Login`, т.е. http://lk.testsite.ru/Account/Login

Comment: Огромное человеческое спасибо, всё получилось!

Comment: @СергейПопков, пожалуйста :)